# org.hibernate.Criteria a bunch of add(Restrictions) extending org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Hi Guys I'm trying to develop a Single Java class which works as a wrapper of something like of org.hibernate.Criteria to get rid of a bunch of add(Restrictions) in a elegant way. Here is what I got so far is a legacy system.

```
public static void prepareForSelect(Criteria crit) {
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("cid","1"));
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("did","2");
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("fdl","3")); //omit for brevity
}
```

Yes is very inadecuate I know that I'm trying to implement a java class which extends org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl and have the properties I need to restrict and I want to. This class have methods like this.

```
public org.hibernate.Criteria addStandartsRestrictions(){
   return this.add(Restrictions.eq("cid",getCid())).add(Restrictions.eq("did",getDid())).add(Restrictions.eq("fdl",getFdl()));
}
```

and in my java code call it like this:

```
org.hibernate.Criteria myOwnCriteria = ((FullCriteria)Session.getSession().createCriteria(MyJava.class)).addStandartsRestrictions();
```

but I'm getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:  org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl cannot be cast to org.com.utilities.classes.FullCriteria
at javaapplication8.JavaApplication8.main(JavaApplication8.java:12)
```

Maybe is something impossible I don't know please guys guide me through.

My wrong implementation.

```
public class FullCriteria extends org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Session.createCriteria()` will never return an instance of your own criteria implementation. And casting the result to your class won't help, as you've seen, because casting never changes the type of an object.

Suppose you have a reference to an Animal. And you **know** that this animal **is** a horse. You can then do that:

```
Horse horse = (Horse) animal;
```

in order to be able to call methods present in Horse and not present in Animal. If the animal is in fact a cow, you'll get a ClassCastException, because a cow is not a horse.

You're using inheritance where you should be using composition. Your class should not extend CriteriaImpl. It should *use*, or *delegate to*, a Criteria instance.

Comment: i have also implements Criteria in my class getting the same error can you provide for me a link to be read something about it.  thanks a lot

Comment: That doesn't change anything. When you call `session.createCriteria()`, you're asking Hibernate to create a criteria for you. Hibernate doesn't know about your class. It creates an instance of its own CriteriaImpl class, and returns it. Let's try to make an analogy. You design a new kind of bike in your garage. Then you go to the bike store, and buy a bike. The bike the store will sell you won't be of the same kind as the bike you designed in your garage. And the fact that both things are bikes doesn't change anything.

Comment: yes you are right that's means is impossible accomplish what i am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Don't type cast `Criteria` object to instance of your own implementation class it throws an error `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl cannot be cast to com.uk.mysqlmaven.domain.CommonLookUpMaster`.

You can get the above error by using below example

**Example:**

```
Session session = SessionFactoryMySqlMaven.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CommonLookUpMaster.class);
CommonLookUpMaster master = (CommonLookUpMaster) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type", type));
```

Using `uniqueResult()` method in `criteria` class we can get the single record based on restrictions.
If you want to get the `single` record then use below example

**Example 1:**

```
Session session = SessionFactoryMySqlMaven.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CommonLookUpMaster.class);
criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type", type));
CommonLookUpMaster master = (CommonLookUpMaster) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

For getting `multiple records as a list` use below example

**Example 2:**

```
Session session = SessionFactoryMySqlMaven.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CommonLookUpMaster.class);
criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type", type));
List<?> list = criteria.list();
```